# Beautiful Soup not locating inner span inside outer span

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to build a price tracker for Udemy courses just as a personal project, since I check the site for sales on courses I'd like to buy pretty often. I'm trying to use Beautiful Soup to snag the price out of the HTML script. Every time I test my code, when it gets to the line: `price = soup.find(class_='usdr-sr-only').get_text()`, it gives me "NoneType object has no attribute 'get_text'" (I'm putting the () after get text in my code).

Here's the line in context:

```
import requests, os, lxml
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

UDEMY_CLASS = input("Please provide the URL for the course whose price you'd like to track: ")
url = UDEMY_CLASS

header = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/122.0.0.0 Safari/537.36",
    "Accept-Language": "en-US,en;q=0.9"
}
response = requests.get(url, headers=header)

soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "lxml")
print(soup.prettify())
        
price = soup.find(class_="usd-sr-only").get_text()
#price_without_currency = price.split("$")[1] not always needed- inspect element
price_as_float = float(price)
```

And the HTML for the part of the page with the price:

```
<div class="base-price-text-module--price-part---xQlz ud-clp-discount-price ud-heading-xl" data-purpose='course-price-text'> == $0
    <span class="ud-sr-only">Current price</span>
        <span>$13.99</span>
```

The first thing I thought it that I told BS to find the wrong class. How should I approach isolating the span with the price text? Appreciate any input, please let me know if I need to add for info.

Comment: Your code is looking for `class_="usd-sr-only"`, but the actual class in the html is `class="ud-sr-only"`.  Those are not the same.  `usd` vs `ud`.

Comment: Ok, true. I fixed that typo and it's still throwing up the exact same error. I also tried making the class "base-price-text-module--price-part---xQlz ud-clp-discount-price ud-heading-xl", but that also returned NoneType.

Comment: Ok, true. I fixed that typo and it's still throwing up the exact same error. I also tried making the class "base-price-text-module--price-part---xQlz ud-clp-discount-price ud-heading-xl", but that also returned NoneType.

Comment: Then the problem is likely because `requests` cannot process javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As requests is blocked by Udemy you can use Selenium instead of requests. You can replace this part of your code:

```
response = requests.get(url, headers=header)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "lxml")
```

with this one:

```
browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=chrome_driver_path)
browser.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(browser.page_source, "lxml")
```

If you want to run script with headless mode (where chrome driver will not open/ run silently) then use this part:

```
options = Options()
options.add_argument('--headless')
browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=chrome_driver_path, options=options)
browser.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(browser.page_source, "lxml")
```

Comment: Thank you! I thought that might have something to do w it. Testing your suggestion when I get to my computer